# How work jQuery DataTable serverSide option

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, datatables

I use jQuery DataTable and  read  [this page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

I can Use `"serverSide": true,` for pagination, sort and etc. on server side. But I do not udrestand how worck it. I thing that DataTable sent parameters to server, for example

> draw  - Type:integer
>   The draw counter that this object is a response to - from
>   the draw parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is
>   strongly recommended for security reasons that you cast this parameter
>   to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it
>   sent in the draw parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting
>   (XSS) attacks.

I add to my controllers method this variable

```
@RequestParam(value = "draw", required = false) Integer draw
```

But I get null value. Then the table itself does not transmit these values and I have to send them to mymself?

How do it?

I want create pagination on server side but I not see examples for spring

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that [library](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables) a while ago:

Example:

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DataTablesOutput<User> getUsers(@Valid DataTablesInput input) {
        return userRepository.findAll(input);
    }
}
```

Maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
     <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```